# Flask reqparser.parse_args with docker passes an ellipsis object - Error

Tags: docker, flask-restful

an issue has been plaguing me recently, being that when I attempt to make a post request with Postman to a service hosted on docker I receive a TypeError:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 554, in update
for key, value in iter_multi_items(mapping):
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable ellipsis object
```

This occurs when this function body is run on a POST from Postman:

```
def post(self):
    from flask_restful import reqparse
    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
    parser.add_argument('rate', type=int, help='Rate cannot be converted')
    parser.add_argument('name')
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

The JSON body passed in the POST request is:

```
{
    "rate" : 1,
    "name" : "Test" 
}
```

I've located the issue with Docker as this only occurs when the service is hosted with docker, if it is hosted locally then no issue occurs.

-- Edit

To give more context, my **init** file looks like this, the error occurring when the POST function is called in postman.

```
from flask import Flask, g
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
import os
import shelve

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

def get_db():
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        db = g._database = shelve.open("rates.db")
    return db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def teardown_db(exception):
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello World"

class RateList(Resource):
    def get(self):
        shelf = get_db()
        keys = list(shelf.keys())

        devices = []

        for key in keys:
            devices.append(shelf[key])

        return {'message' : 'Success', 'data' : devices}, 200

    def post(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('rate', type=int, help='Rate cannot be converted')
        parser.add_argument('name')
        args = parser.parse_args()

        shelf = get_db()
        shelf[args['rate']] = args

        return {'message' : 'Rate registered', 'data' : args}, 201

class Rate(Resource):
    def get(self, rate):
        shelf = get_db()

        if not(rate in shelf):
            return {'message' : 'Rate not found', 'data' : {}}, 404
        
        return {'message' : 'Rate found', 'data' : shelf[rate]}, 200

    def delete(self, rate):
        shelf = get_db()

        if not(rate in shelf):
            return {'message' : 'Rate not found', 'data' : {}}, 404
        
        del shelf[rate]
        return {'message' : 'Rate deleted', 'data' : {}}, 200

api.add_resource(RateList, '/Rate')
api.add_resource(Rate, '/Rate/<string:rate>')
```

Docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
    stock-registry:
        build: .
        volumes:
            - .:/usr/src/app
        ports:
            - 5001:80
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["python", "./run.py"]
```

Run.py:

```
from stock_registry import app
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

The complete error log that shows when this is attempted:

```
172.22.0.1 - - [30/Jun/2021 12:37:12] "POST /shares HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__

return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app

response = self.handle_exception(e)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 265, in error_router

return original_handler(e)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 32, in reraise

raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app

response = self.full_dispatch_request()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request

rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 265, in error_router

return original_handler(e)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 32, in reraise

raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request

rv = self.dispatch_request()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request

return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 446, in wrapper

resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 84, in view

return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 550, in dispatch_request

resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/src/app/stock_registry/__init__.py", line 65, in post

args = parser.parse_args()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_restful/reqparse.py", line 261, in parse_args

value, found = arg.parse(req)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_restful/reqparse.py", line 143, in parse

source = self.source(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_restful/reqparse.py", line 101, in source

values.update(value)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 554, in update

for key, value in iter_multi_items(mapping):


TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable ellipsis object
```

Comment: Please include all of the relevant details in this question; don't hide them behind a link, even if it's to another SO question.  If you say the issue only happens in Docker, make sure to include your Dockerfile and any details on how you're launching the container.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have added the relevant information to the question.